# When and why some items don't even get compared in a sorting algorithm?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

I have a case where I need to sort an array of strings by multi-criteria. Just imagine that we're copying a list of directory paths. Given the requirements below, I need the sorting to produce **always** the same result. The initial order of the input should not matter.

- Each item is a path string that **might** contain a glob/wildcard star `*` anywhere.
  e.g. `*/foo` or `foo/*` or `foo/*/bar`.. you get the idea.
- Each item **might** also contain a prefix `!` which negates the value.
  e.g. `!bar/norf` would mean remove this path.

#### Requirements:

1. If two compared paths are equal and one of them is negated (`!`); the negated should come last.
   e.g. `bar/norf` comes before `!bar/norf`
2. Paths with less number of levels should come first.
   e.g. `foo/bar` comes before `foo/baz/*`
3. Loose paths/globs should come first, verbose/exact paths should come last.
   e.g. `foo/*` comes before `foo/bar/*` comes before `foo/bar/baz`.

#### Attempts:

Now if I use algorithms such as quick-sort or merge-sort, most of the time I get the expected result but when I change the initial order or number of items, it fails. Especially for the first requirement above. Bec. sometimes (depending on the initial order or the number of items) some items do not get compared to each other directly.

```js
var unsorted_CASE1 = [ 
    'foo/bar/baz', 
    '!bar/norf', 
    'bar/x', 
    'bar/norf', 
    '!foo/*/baz', 
    '!bar/*', 
    'foo/qux/*' 
];
console.log( mergeSort(unsorted_CASE1, compareFn) );
// expected correct output
[ 
    '!bar/*',      // 0
    'bar/norf',    // 1
    '!bar/norf',   // 2
    'bar/x',       // 3
    '!foo/*/baz',  // 4
    'foo/qux/*',   // 5
    'foo/bar/baz'  // 6
]

var unsorted_CASE2 = [
    'foo/bar/baz',
    '!bar/norf',
    'bar/x',
    'bar/norf',
    '!foo/*/baz',
    '!bar/*',
    '!foo/qux/boo', // added a new item here, no other change
    'foo/qux/*'
];
console.log( mergeSort(unsorted_CASE2, compareFn) );
// incorrect output
[ 
    '!bar/*',      // 0
    '!bar/norf',   // 1 (should have come after bar/norf (3))
    'bar/x',       // 2
    'bar/norf',    // 3
    '!foo/*/baz',  // 4
    'foo/qux/*',   // 5
    'foo/bar/baz', // 6
    '!foo/qux/boo' // 7
]
```

Here `'!bar/norf'` and `'bar/norf'` are never compared directly to each other. As a result, the negated came first which was expected to come after.

**EDIT 1:** I'm not asking for an sorting algorithm implementation. I'm of course using external libs for that. I'm trying to understand when and why some items do not get compared and produce this result. And does the sorting algorithm to be used here requires all the permutations possible to get the expected result. If not, which well-known algorithm fits best here? Or is it not the sorting algorithm? That's all.

**EDIT 2:**
Here is the compare function:

```js
function compareFn(oA, oB) {
    var aNeg = oA.slice(0, 1) === '!',
        bNeg = oB.slice(0, 1) === '!',
        a = aNeg ? oA.slice(1) : oA,
        b = bNeg ? oB.slice(1) : oB;
    // "foo/bar" vs "!foo/bar" » equal » negated wins (comes last)
    if (a === b) {
        return aNeg ? 1 : -1;
    }
    // if not equal » e.g. "!*/foo/*" vs "*/foo/bar"
    // "*/foo/bar" comes last
    var A = a.split('/'),
        B = b.split('/'),
        numLevelsA = A.length,
        numLevelsB = B.length;
    // glob having the less number of levels comes first
    // e.g. "bar/*" comes before "bar/baz/*"
    if (numLevelsA < numLevelsB || a === '*') { return -1; } // a first
    if (numLevelsA > numLevelsB || b === '*') { return 1; } // b first
    // number of levels are equal:
    var lA, lB, i = -1;
    while (++i < numLevelsA) {
        lA = A[i];
        lB = B[i];
        // levels are not equal
        if (lA !== lB) {
            // "*" comes before "a*bc"
            // level IS star "*"
            if (lA === '*' && lB !== '*') { return -1; }
            if (lA !== '*' && lB === '*') { return 1; }
            // level has star "a*bc"
            if (lA.indexOf('*') >= 0 && lB.indexOf('*') < 0) { return -1; }
            if (lA.indexOf('*') < 0 && lB.indexOf('*') >= 0) { return 1; }
        }
        // else if levels are equal,
        // continue to next level
    }
    // no order
    return 0;
};
```

***Note***: This is a very simplified version of the problem. I'm not implementing a minimatch or similar library. (In fact items are not even path strings). So please don't suggest libs that already do this. I'm trying to establish/understand the logic.

Comment: Can't you use any external library?

Comment: Where's the question? are you asking for an algorithm? Asking how something works? Which algorithm should you use? Why didn't you include the compareFn if you're asking the question presented in the title? It just doesn't seem clear what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: @thefourtheye For what? I'm trying to understand when and why some items are not compared directly and produce this result. I'm already using external libs for sort algorithms.

Comment: @OnurYıldırım JavaScript specification doesn't mandate stability of the sorting algorithm. So its purely an implementation detail.

Comment: @KevinB, I thought it was obvious after writing this long. I've edited the question. I don't need an algorithm. There are many well-known algorithms. I need help to see which one suits here best. There is nothing special with the `compareFn`. I think it's irrelevant but I'll include it in a sec.

Comment: So you're basically asking, should you use mergeSort, quickSort, insertionSort, or some other, right?

Comment: Since you have incorrect output in your second case, I think the comparison function is absolute germane to the question.

Comment: @thefourtheye I've read that too thanks. The stability I'm looking for is somewhat different than that though. Stability: if two items compare as equal, then their relative order will be preserved. But in this case, some items do not even get compared.

Comment: @OnurYıldırım: Not comparing every item is exactly the point of using something like mergesort! If items that should have been compared aren't being compared it's because something is wrong with your comparison function. Provide your comparison function and, if possible, an actual runable example.

Comment: Is the question really which "*sorting* algorithm"? As long as the sort comparison has a total order it doesn't really matter - and if not, it's not a "sorting" problem.

Comment: wow! is this question that vauge?

Comment: *"algorithm"* in general is vague, it could mean your compare function or the js engine's implementation.

Comment: @KevinB, seriously? After reading this long long question! I thought I've made it clear that I don't need an algorithm. Maybe the title is the problem..

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, No I don't. I've included the compare function.

Comment: @OnurYıldırım: I'd suggest removing the sections about sorting algorithms. Stability only matters if the paths are otherwise considered exactly the same.

Comment: What exactly do you need? spell it out. To me it looks like your comparison function is the problem, but you seem to be completely ignoring that possibility which I think is where all this confusion is coming from.

Comment: That a really complicated looking comparison function for what shouldn't be that complicated a set of criteria.

Comment: Based on the criteria provided, I would have expected the compare function to first compare # of paths, followed by alphabetic sorting from first path to last path, and then finally the negation if both paths are equal. but, you started with the negation.

Comment: Absolutely what @KevinB said. Sort your criteria into order of the most differentiating first (level) to least differentiating (negation) and implement your comparison accordingly.

Comment: @KevinB, Spelling this... If you think it's the compare function, well I'll learn from you. Do I need an algo that runs all the permutations for this? Do I need `a` and `b` to get compared so that `!foo/bar` comes after `foo/bar`?

Comment: The order that you apply the comparison is very important as it may dictate which values are compared against each other.

Comment: @KevinB, Ok. I'll move the equality comparison to bottom and try..

Comment: And why do you have `a.split('.')`? Shouldn't that be `a.split('/')`? You don't have any `.` in your paths!

Comment: @MattBurland, It's from the original source. I've edited that. Thanks.

Comment: And you have `A === '*'` which is comparing an array to a string?

Comment: @MattBurland, that's definitely incorrect. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, `compareFn('foo/bar', 'foo/baz/*')` returns `-1` which is expected. Item with less number of levels come first.

Comment: why is  `bar/norf` after `bar/x` ?

Comment: @OnurYıldırım To answer your question title, if `a<b` and `b<c`, we don't have to compare `a` and `c` - we already know `a<c`.  This is because sorting only makes sense if the comparison function is transitive, so the algorithms assume that.

Comment: @2astalavista This is not a lexicographical order and we don't count the chars either. `bar/norf` and `bar/x` are equivalent in the required sorting.

Comment: @AaronDufour The main concern in the example is the comparison between `a` and `!a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote the compare function from scratch and *I think* this one works:

```
function compare(a, b) {
    // trivial case, both are exactly the same!
    if (a === b) {
        return 0;
    }
    var levelsA = a.split("/");
    var levelsB = b.split("/");

    // Check depth (number of levels)
    if (levelsA.length === levelsB.length) {
        // count wildcards (assuming more wildcards comes first)
        var wild = /(?:^|\/)\*(?:$|\/)/g;
        var mA = a.match(wild);
        var mB = b.match(wild);
        var wildA = mA ? mA.length : 0;
        var wildB = mB ? mB.length : 0;
        if (wildA === wildB) {
            // check for negation
            var negA = a.indexOf("!") === 0;
            var negB = b.indexOf("!") === 0;
            if (negA === negB) {
                // both are negated or neither are, just return alphabetical
                return a < b ? -1 : 1;
            }
            // compare without the negatation
            var nonNegA = negA ? a.slice(1) : a;
            var nonNegB = negB ? b.slice(1) : b;
            if (nonNegA === nonNegB) {
                return negA ? 1 : -1;
            }
            return nonNegA < nonNegB ? -1 : 1;

        }
        return wildA > wildB ? -1 : 1;
    }

    return levelsA.length < levelsB.length ? -1 : 1;
}
```

There are probably some optimizations that could be done and it hasn't been extensively tested, but given `unsorted_CASE2` this seems to produce the desired result:

```
unsorted_CASE2.sort(compare);
```

Gives:

```
[
    "!bar/*",
    "bar/norf",
    "!bar/norf",
    "bar/x",
    "!foo/*/baz",
    "foo/qux/*",
    "foo/bar/baz",
    "!foo/qux/boo"
]
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. This seems to work perfectly. And +1 for answering a down-voted. This proves I'm wrong claiming that; the comparison function is irrelevant when and whether two items get compared directly to each other. Furthermore, Sorting the criteria in the order of the most differentiating first to least differentiating is the solution.